# T-SQL Object Definition null for tables with non-null create statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to select the create statement for a table in T-SQL like

```
select OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('dbo.tablename', 'U'))
```

but it always returns null. I have the view definition permission on the table in question, and when I'm in SQL Server Management Studio, I can see the definition by right clicking on the table and going to `Script View As > Create To > New Query Editor Window`, which does show the create statement for the table.

The problem seems to be with `OBJECT_DEFINITION` because

```
select OBJECT_ID('dbo.tablename', 'U')
```

returns the table's id integer without issue. Does anyone know what the cause of this problem could be.

Comment: The source DDL from tables is not stored in the catalog. You can use the [SMO Scripter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/scripting) with PowerShell or .NET language tot generate DDL for tables, indexes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [OBJECT_DEFINITION()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql) with User Tables (type `'U'`):

> OBJECT_DEFINITION applies to the following object types:
>
> C = Check constraint
>
> D = Default (constraint or stand-alone)
>
> P = SQL stored procedure
>
> FN = SQL scalar function
>
> R = Rule
>
> RF = Replication filter procedure
>
> TR = SQL trigger (schema-scoped DML trigger, or DDL trigger at either the database or server scope)
>
> IF = SQL inline table-valued function
>
> TF = SQL table-valued function
>
> V = View